# $H^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ is embedded in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In a research paper https://hal.science/hal-02891557/, the authors used the embedding of $H^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (see page 16-line 1) to obtain some estimates in their research paper. Here, $\Omega$ is a  bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with smooth boundary.

Is this because of the definition of $H^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ that is the closure of $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $H^{2}(\Omega)$  which means that any function in $H^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$  can be approximated by a sequence of smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes, you have answered Q1 correctly yourself. As to the second question, how do you define $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$?

Comment: No, this is thanks to Sobolev embeddings, and this work because $\Omega$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, not $\Bbb R^N$ (this would work in general for $N\leq 3$). It will work for any sufficiently nice domain (say $C^1$, or more generally, under a cone condition) and a good reference might be the book "Sobolev Spaces" by Adams and Fournier.

Comment: Thank you very much @LSK21. $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ are closed with positive measure.

Comment: Thank you very much @LL 3.14.